# JTable sorting int in undesired order

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to create a `JTable` combined with `DefaultTableModel`. My problem is that, when I'm clicking to sort it (row with prices) it sorts incorrectly.

Say we have row:

```
2
6
3
112
42
1
```

What I want:

```
1
2
3
6
42
112
```

What I get:

```
1
112
2
3
42
6
```

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: For better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: You need to set the class of that column as an integer. override the tableModel. Right now it's probably sorting based on an object comparison/string comparison.

Comment: Yes, what EricR is saying is correct. To explain further: each character - be it a letter, number, punctuation mark, etc. - has a Unicode number assigned to it. For example, the computer doesn't see `"A"`, it sees `65`. The computer is sorting by this instead of the numbers themselves. For example, the Unicode number for `"1"` is `49`. So it sees that the smallest is `49` and puts that at the top. Then, it sees `49 49 50` and puts that next. Next is `50`, then `50 49`, then `51`, then `52 50`. It's sorting like alphabetization: the first letter first, then the next if there's a tie, and so on.

Answer (score 7):

An example from my one of my project's codebase. This belongs in your TableModel

```
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            switch (col) {
                case 0:
                    return Integer.class;
                case 1:
                    return String.class;
                case 2:
                    return String.class;
                case 3:
                    return Integer.class;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You should mention that this belongs into the TableModel